# Over ride default fetch to skip rows with certain values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Java, Hibernate, Spring Data and fairly new to this technology. **I need to figure out how to Skip rows that are marked as 'archived.'** We have a strict guidance from our DB architect that no rows shall be deleted from the database.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity implements Identifiable<String> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy="uuid")
    private String id;

    private boolean archived; //<----?
} 

@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractEntity {        
    private String title;
    private String fullName;
    @ManyToOne
    private Department dept;
}

@Entity
public class Department extends AbstractEntity {        
    private String name;    
}
```

In the above example, any class extending AbstractEntity should never return rows that have archived == true. All my domain classes will be extending AbstractEntity so **I'd like a solution that's either implemented in AbstractEntity.java or at some global configuration** so that all generated SQL calls are *'where [table].archived <> true'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Hibernate Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html#objectstate-filters).

```
@FilterDef(name="activeOnly")
@Filter(name="activeOnly", condition= "archived <> 1")
// assumes that all tables have a numeric column "archived"
// as you can notice, this is a filter at the SQL Level 
//  (not at the Entity level)
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity // ....
```

I've never used Spring Data, but the [Adding custom behavior to all repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) section  of the official documentation lead me to belieave that it is quite easy to obtain an injected `EntityManager` and customize its behaviour. Just unwrap it and enable the filter.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class); 
session.enableFilter("activeOnly");
```

If you want the filter to be applied for all subclasses of the `@MappedSuperclass` use a recent version of Hibernate. Only version 3.5 and greater (see [HHH-4332](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4332)) supports this behaviour.

Also, there is one gotcha, you may need to repeat the filter on associations (See [Hibernate Filters on related table with MappedSuperClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788912/hibernate-filters-on-related-table-with-mappedsuperclass)).

---

If you want to customize the delete operations as well, use [`@SQLDelete`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#querysql-cud) to mark `archived = 1` (see  [Soft deletes using Hibernate annotations](http://featurenotbug.com/2009/07/soft-deletes-using-hibernate-annotations/)). But to the best of my knowledge this only works on mapped entities (nothing can be done at the `@MappedSuperclass` level)